# Jmeter Pre-request Script to set value of HTTP Headers

Tags: javascript, jmeter, postman

I am trying to execute a pre-request script in Jmeter (similar to what you can do in postman) in order to set Header values at the beginning of every request. 
How I can do it?

I am trying to set some Header values in my HTTP Header Manager when the request is made with the pre-request script script below. The values for these headers should be set by this script.

This is the script that I use in postman:

```
var client = "SHA256 Credential=" + environment["id"];
var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('client', client);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('timestamp', timestamp);
```

(`environment["id"]` being a preset header).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have `id` set as a [User Defined Variable](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) you can add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of your request and configure it to add the following headers:

1. Name: `client`, Value: `SHA256 Credential=${id}`
2. Name: `timestamp`, Value: `${__groovy(Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000),)}`

Where:

- `${id}` is a reference to the `id` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) (you need to set it somehow)
- [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) is a JMeter Function allowing execution of arbitrary [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code

Answer (score 1):

Postman have 4 variable scopes:

> - Global
> - Environment
> - Local
> - Data

JMeter have 3 variable scopes:

> - Global
> - Thread Local
> - Data

check [JMeter environment specific configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509990/jmeter-environment-specific-configuration) answers for more info, but you can use jmeter property file and in each environment override with [different property file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) to launch jmeter

> -G[prop_name]=[value]
>
> defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.
>
> -G[propertyfile]
>
> defines a file containing JMeter properties to be sent to all remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

While passing the values to Jmeter you can pass the header values like this  -
sh jmeter.sh -Jtimestamp =timestamp.

Then you can easily access the value of timestamp in HTTP Header manager using ${__property(timestamp)}