# How to run environment based execution using same set of script in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to run same script in different environments like QC, UAT and PROD. I would like to know how do we configure and run based on specified environments.

Note - I tried with properties file but it requires some manual effort which we do not want.

Please help with some examples

Answer (score 0):

If environments don't change you can create 3 separate [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration elements containing protocol/host/port/path/etc. settings for different environments and depending on the target environment you can toggle this or that HTTP Request Defaults element.

If you need unattended way of enabling/disabling HTTP Requests Defaults (or any other test element) you can consider using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, it provides [syntax to enable/disable any JMeter test element via YAML config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) or via command-line arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have done something as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509990/jmeter-environment-specific-configuration/22532588 using if controller,jp@gc-Parameterized Controller and Module Controller but I am facing in UDV defined hostname=UAT and hostname=QC whenever I ran it executes from UAT because UAT is in 1stplace and if I mention QC in 1stplace then it executes from QC. I want solution something like based on CLI mode based on this script should execute and unable to do
jmeter -n -t Trial.jmx -l test.csv -Jhostname=qc  - Should execute in QC env